# Statement + "I don't think"?

Tags: idioms, syntactic-analysis, negation

Yesterday I said, 'there's nothing interesting, I don't think' and I thought about it afterwards. Obviously I *do* think, but that's not how it's said. It's always "I *don't* think". Is this an idiom or a corruption of language? Is it used in US English? Would "I don't think" be considered informal language?

Comment: @Laurel I read that, but I was hoping for some more detail.

Comment: WS2 adds detail.